# webpack async code splitting based on routes loads all chunks in all the routes

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, code-splitting, code-splitting-async

I have enabled route based chunking in my react application.

I have used **require.ensure**

```
require.ensure([], function(require) {
require('./Component1');
});
```

My app contains two routes **/home** and **/pro**

Here is my **route.js**

```
        const React = require('react');
        const ReactRouter = require('react-router');
        const Router = ReactRouter.Router;
        const Route = ReactRouter.Route;
        const browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;


        var ProHomeContainer = "";
        if (typeof (require.ensure) == "function") {
            ProHomeContainer = require.ensure([], function (require) {
                require('./containers/ProHomeContainer.js');
        },"Home");
        } 

        var HomeContainer = "";
        if (typeof (require.ensure) == "function") {
            HomeContainer = require.ensure([], function (require) {
                require('./containers/HomeContainer.js');
        },"ProHome")
        } 

        export const routes = (
        <Router history={browserHistory} >
            <Route path={'/home'} getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
                    if (typeof (require.ensure) == "function") {
                        require.ensure([], (require) => {
                            callback(null, require('./containers/HomeContainer.js'));

                        }, "Home")
                    } else {
                        callback(null, require('./containers/HomeContainer.js'), "Home");
                    }
            } } />
            <Route path={'/pro'} getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
                    if (typeof (require.ensure) == "function") {
                        require.ensure([], (require) => {
                            callback(null, require('./containers/ProHomeContainer.js'));

                        }, "ProHome")
                    } else {
                        callback(null, require('./containers/ProHomeContainer.js'));
                    }
            } } />
        </Router >
        );
```

Webpack identifies the **require.ensure** and creates a separate chunk for /home and /pro

**Home.js** and **ProHomejs** correspondingly.[image]

Now the problem is when I open **/home** it should load only **Home.js** (chunk of /home) but it will load **ProHome.js** as well.

If this is the case then there is no benefit of using route based chunking ?

Is there any better way to route based chunking ? Please point to right resources

Comment: Can you check what is the value of typeof require.ensure?

Comment: Hi vivek, as i am using Server side rendering require.ensure was not a function , so added this check to avoid failing server side code